# What is the best way to read from a table?

Tags: javascript

I have made a form with the possibility to select different values (x and y):

```
<form>
    X: <select id="value_x">
    </select>
    Y: <select id="value_y">
    </select>
</form>
<div id="result_z"></div>
```

In the selects I have multiple options, for example 5, 20, 26 and more.

Now I have made a Javascript code that reads the values from both selects, and store it into two variables. In an empty div (result_z) the value Z should be displayed. In an Excel document I have made the result of Z. For example:

```
***12***  -  ***14***  -  ***16***  -  ***25***  -  ***30***  -  ***40***
***14***  -  36  -  12  -  12  -  23  -  28
***16***  -  45  -  34  -  34  -  34  -  35
***18***  -  47  -  56  -  46  -  56  -  48
***20***  -  89  -  78  -  56  -  78  -  70
```

You can see that if X=14 and Y=16 the Z-value should be 45, and if X=30 and Y=20 the Z value should be 78. But what is the best way to create that table in JavaScript? A MySQL database would be the best option, but I would like a solution without a database. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a two-dimesional array to store your table.
Then give 12, 14, 16... indexes. you can use self made objects or just plain arrays for that too.
Then when you select values, you can lookup your result and display it in your div.

like this:

```
     <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p = {
            table: [[16, 32], [8, 19]],
            horizontal: [12, 15],
            vertical: [6, 14],
            selectOnchange: function() {
                var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
                var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
                document.getElementById("z").value = this.table[Number(x)][Number(y)];
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        x: <select id="x" onchange="p.selectOnchange()"><option value="0">12</option><option value="1">15</option></select><br />
        y: <select id="y" onchange="p.selectOnchange()"><option value="0">6</option><option value="1">14</option></select><br />
        <input id="z"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a two-dimensional array, where x and y are your keys:

```
var myarray = new Array();
myarray[14] = new Array();
myarray[14][14] = 36;
myarray[14][16] = 45;
...

alert(myarray[14][16]); // Get Z-value for X: 14, Y: 16
```